# How to call method from another kodi/xbmc addon

Tags: python, add-on, xbmc, kodi

I am trying to make an addon which calls another script addon. Now what I want to know is how can I access methods of the second addon from the first one. If yes please someone provide me with the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy....

Add the addon id of the addon whoes function you ant ot call
and add these

For example: To call function from add-on #1 in add-on #2

Add-on #1: Write extension point as xbmc.python.module and provide add-on's library path as below.

```
<extension point="xbmc.python.module" library="resources" />
```

Add-on #2: Write add-on #1 add-on id, in requires tag import as below mention.

```
<requires>
<import addon="add-on #1 id" version="2.7.0"/>
<requires>
```

Now got to the addon whoes function you want to call and add the .py files to resources directory in your addon.

Now,

```
from resources import foo

foo()
```

and it is done